# Calculating the Determinant for a 4x4 matrix - (The RayTracer Challenge) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, matrix, raytracing

I am trying to write a raytracer in Javascript/Canvas, working from "The Ray Tracer Challenge" (Jamis Buck). I wrote code that successfully calculated the determinant of a 3x3 matrix, but it failed for a 4x4 matrix, so I deleted the code, and instead have the following code I converted from C code. (The compiled C version works.) It doesn't come up with the correct determinant for a 4x4 input matrix, even though it is ported from C, where it DOES work.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

(I have included the original, working, C code at the bottom.)

```
"use strict";
// HELPER FUNCTION

function initArray(rows, cols)  {

var result = [];

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)  {

    result[r] = [];

    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)  {

        result[r][c] = 0;
    }
}

return result;
}


//--------------------------------
// DETERMINANT

// Function to get cofactor of mat[p][q] in temp[][]. n is current 

// dimension of mat[][] 

function getCofactor(mat, temp, p, q, n)
{


var i = 0, j = 0; 

// Looping for each element of the matrix 
for (var row = 0; row < n; row++) 
{ 
    for (var col = 0; col < n; col++) 
    { 
        // Copying into temporary matrix only those element 
        // which are not in given row and column 
        if (row != p && col != q) 
        { 
            temp[i][j++] = mat[row][col];

            // Row is filled, so increase row index and 
            // reset col index 
            if (j == n - 1) 
            {
                j = 0; 
                i++; 
            }
        }
    } 
}

return temp;
}


/* Recursive function for finding determinant of matrix. 
n is current dimension of mat[][]. */

function determinantOfMatrix(mat, n) 
{ 

var D = 0; // Initialize result 

// Base case : if matrix contains single element 
if (n == 1) 
    return mat[0][0]; 

var temp = initArray(4, 4); // To store cofactors 

var sign = 1; // To store sign multiplier 

// Iterate for each element of first row 
for (var f = 0; f < n; f++) 
{ 
    // Getting Cofactor of mat[0][f] 
    temp = getCofactor(mat, temp, 0, f, n); 
    D += sign * mat[0][f] * determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1); 

    // terms are to be added with alternate sign 
    sign = -sign; 
}

return D; 
} 

// Finally, this is how I test it:

function test7()    {

var m = initArray(4, 4);

m[0][0] = -2, m[0][1] = -8, m[0][2] = 3, m[0][3] = 5;
m[1][0] = -3, m[1][1] = 1, m[1][2] = 7, m[1][3] = 3;
m[2][0] = 1, m[2][1] = 2, m[2][2] = -9, m[2][3] = 6;
m[3][0] = 6, m[3][1] = 7, m[3][2] = 7, m[3][3] = -9;

/* 4x4 TEST MATRIX

    -2,    -8,    3,    5
    -3,     1,    7,    3
     1,     2,   -9,    6
     6,     7,    7,   -9

*/

var determinant = determinantOfMatrix(m, 4 /*m.length*/);

alert("determinant = " + determinant); // SHOULD BE -4071
}
```

//---------------------- BELOW IS THE C CODE, WHICH WORKS --------

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Dimension of input square matrix 

#define N 4 

// Function to get cofactor of mat[p][q] in temp[][]. n is current 
// dimension of mat[][] 

void getCofactor(int mat[N][N], int temp[N][N], int p, int q, int n) 
{ 

int i = 0, j = 0; 

// Looping for each element of the matrix 
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) 
{ 
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) 
    { 
        // Copying into temporary matrix only those element 
        // which are not in given row and column 
        if (row != p && col != q) 
        { 
            temp[i][j++] = mat[row][col]; 

            // Row is filled, so increase row index and 
            // reset col index 
            if (j == n - 1) 
            { 
                j = 0; 
                i++; 
            }
        } 
    }
}
} 

/* Recursive function for finding determinant of matrix. 
n is current dimension of mat[][]. */

int determinantOfMatrix(int mat[N][N], int n) 
{ 

int D = 0; // Initialize result 

// Base case : if matrix contains single element 
if (n == 1) 
    return mat[0][0]; 

int temp[N][N]; // To store cofactors 

int sign = 1; // To store sign multiplier 

// Iterate for each element of first row 
for (int f = 0; f < n; f++) 
{ 
    // Getting Cofactor of mat[0][f] 
    getCofactor(mat, temp, 0, f, n); 
    D += sign * mat[0][f] * determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1); 

    // terms are to be added with alternate sign 
    sign = -sign; 
}

return D; 
} 


// Driver program to test above functions 

int main() 
{ 

int mat[N][N] = {{-2, -8, 3, 5}, 
                {-3, 1, 7, 3},
                {1, 2, -9, 6}, 
                {-6, 7, 7, -9} 
                }; 

printf("Determinant of the matrix is : %d", determinantOfMatrix(mat, N)); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Very important: always work in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so you’re forced to declare your variables and don’t end up with unpleasant reentrancy surprises.

Comment: (That’s actually probably the problem, specifically with the undeclared variable `f`.)

Comment: I tried "use strict", it still didn't work. Also, please note Ive just edited the test7() function slightly, the function call was referencing "m2" instead of "m", I've updated it. That obviously wasn't the problem... In adding "use strict", I also updated the var creations in the various for loops with explicit "var" declerations....

Comment: `m.rows`? `m` doesn’t have a `rows` property.

Comment: The input for the C and Javascript versions is different: The two `m[3][0]` differ in signs. (You can use `m.length` instead of `m.rows`, and you probably want `var temp = initArray(n - 1, n - 1)` in `getCofactor`.)

Comment: The inputs for the C and Javascript versions need to be different; the code is ported, and Javascript doesn't do pass-by-reference. initArray(rows,cols) does not need to be 0-based (and isn't), thus do not need to call initArray with (n - 1, n -1). Sorry about the m.rows thing, it was left over from a prev iteration of the code... Still doesn't work.

Comment: You still have a 6 instead of a -6 at `[3][0]`, like @MOehm said.

Comment: Thank you for lecturing me. I thought you wanted to know what's wrong with your code. But you're not really interested, you just want to keep on posting "Still doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry, I apologize. I didn't actually mean that tone, I just don't get out much. I really do want to understand, I've updated minor errors in the code as I've gone.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for the clue, I shall take it into account. Presumably the problem is with Javascript semantics, as I am getting the same erroneous result from both the algorithm in the book (when applied to 4x4 matrices), and the code above, ported from the C code. I shall look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know why your code doesn't work. However, I tried translating the code and this below work.

```
var N = 4; 
function initArray(rows, cols)  {
    var result = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)  {
        result[r] = [];

        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) result[r][c] = 0;

    }

    return result;
}

function getCofactor(mat, temp, p, q, n){ 
    var i = 0, j = 0;

// Looping for each element of the matrix 
    for (var row = 0; row < n; row++) { 
        for (var col = 0; col < n; col++) { 
            // Copying into temporary matrix only those element 
            // which are not in given row and column 
            if (row != p && col != q) { 
                temp[i][j++] = mat[row][col]; 

                // Row is filled, so increase row index and 
                // reset col index 
                if (j === n - 1) { 
                    j = 0; 
                    i++; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 

/* Recursive function for finding determinant of matrix. 
n is current dimension of mat[][]. */

function determinantOfMatrix(mat, n) {

    var D = 0; // Initialize result 

    // Base case : if matrix contains single element 
    if (n == 1) return mat[0][0]; 

    var temp = initArray(N,N); // To store cofactors 

    var sign = 1; // To store sign multiplier 

    // Iterate for each element of first row 
    for (var f = 0; f < n; f++) { 
        // Getting Cofactor of mat[0][f] 
        getCofactor(mat, temp, 0, f, n); 
        D += sign * mat[0][f] * determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1); 

        // terms are to be added with alternate sign 
        sign = -sign; 
    }

    return D; 
} 

// Driver program to test above functions 
var mat = [[-2, -8, 3, 5], 
           [-3, 1, 7, 3],
           [1, 2, -9, 6], 
           [-6, 7, 7, -9]
          ];

alert("Determinant of the matrix is : " + 
determinantOfMatrix(mat, N));
```

Comment: I have just discovered that you answered. It is very late and I am in bed. I will test this code in the morning, but Thank You so much for this. You're very kind.

Comment: I got out of bed, I tested it. It works. Thank you very much. Also, I apologise for the way I initialised the matrix in my code, haha! I have MCI, and sometimes I don't engage my brain properly.... Thanks again!